# opening file with php thread

Tags: php, regex, multithreading, file-io, pthreads

we have a huge text file ( about 1 gig ) and we want search in it with php , 
for that i open some part of this text with some thread and search in this parts . 
like below :

```
class AsyncFileRequest extends Thread
{   public $from_line;
    public $to_line;
    public $line;
    public $n;
    public $ans;
    public $handle;
        public function __construct($handle,$from_line,$to_line) {
        $this->handle =$handle = @fopen($handle, 'r');
        $this->from_line =$from_line;
        $this->to_line =$to_line;
    }    
    public function run() {
        if (($handle = $this->handle) &&
            ($from_line = $this->from_line) &&
            ($to_line = $this->to_line) 
            ) {       
            $n=0;
            $ans="";
            while($line=stream_get_line($handle,65535,"\n")) {

                $n++;
                if($n>=$from_line){
                    $ans.=$line;
                }
                if ($n == $to_line) {
                    break;
                }
             }
             fclose($handle);
             $this->data=$ans;
        } else printf("Thread #%lu was not provided a URL<br>\n", $this->getThreadId());
    }
}
```

but if i use more part for open it's took long time to process this , what we do for open huge file part by part with php thread ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to open the handle in the run method, this is so that each thread is sure to have a unique handle to the file.

A thread will work, however preferable is the Pools execution model; let the Pool decide which thread to execute in, use a sensible size pool for the hardware and task and just keep submitting tasks until all the work is done.

Then wait for the pool to shutdown and you can reap the data from tasks using Pool::collect.

For example:

```
<?php
/* A pooled task to read specific lines from a file */
class LineReader extends Collectable {

    public function __construct($file, $start, $lines) {
        $this->file  = $file;
        $this->start = $start;
        $this->lines = $lines;
    }

    public function run() {
        /* don't write the handle to the object scope */
        $handle = fopen($this->file, "r");
        $line   = 1;
        $count  = 0;

        while (($next = fgets($handle))) {
            if ($line >= $this->start) {
                if ($count < $this->lines) {
                    $lines .= $next;
                    $count++;
                } else break;
            }
            $line++;
        }

        $this->data = $lines;

        /* close handle */
        fclose($handle);

        /* finished with object */
        $this->setGarbage();
    }
}

$pool = new Pool(8);
/* submit enough tasks to read entire file */
$pool->submit(
    new LineReader(__FILE__, 1, 10));
$pool->submit(
    new LineReader(__FILE__, 10, 10));
$pool->submit(
    new LineReader(__FILE__, 20, 10));
$pool->submit(
    new LineReader(__FILE__, 30, 10));
$pool->submit(
    new LineReader(__FILE__, 40, 10));
$pool->submit(
    new LineReader(__FILE__, 50, 10));
$pool->submit(
    new LineReader(__FILE__, 60, 10));

/* force all reading to complete */
$pool->shutdown();

/* cleanup pool, and echo data to show working */
$pool->collect(function(LineReader $reader){
    foreach(preg_split("~\n~", $reader->data) as $line) {
        printf(
            "%04d: %s\n", $reader->start++, $line);
    }

    /* allow object to be free'd */
    return $reader->isGarbage();
});
?>
```